# Check null value in a quiz

Tags: vue.js

I did a quiz with vue.js and i would like to check if a value is null before put it in the console.log. I Can't find how to do that...
I have a lot of questions to put in this quiz but some of them just need to be ignored in the final result. I just want to bypass all the questions with value:null.

```
"use strict";

window.onload = function() {

    var quiz = {
        title: 'Quizz',

        questions: [{
                text: "Question 1",
                responses: [{
                        text: 'a',
                        value: null,
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'b',
                        value: null,
                    }
                ]
            },           
            {
                text: "Question 2",
                responses: [{
                        text: 'a',
                        value: '1',
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'b',
                        value: '2',
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    };

    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            quiz: quiz,
            questionIndex: 0,
            userResponses: Array(),
            show: true
        },
        methods: {
            // Go to next question
            next: function() {
                console.log(this.userResponses);
                           this.questionIndex++;
            },
            // Go to previous question
            prev: function() {
               this.questionIndex--;
            },
            score: function() {
                //find the highest occurence in responses
                var userResponses = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], this.userResponses);
                var modeMap = {};
                var maxEl = userResponses,
                    maxCount = 1;
                for (var i = 0; i < userResponses.length; i++) {
                    var el = userResponses[i];
                    if (modeMap[el] == null)
                        modeMap[el] = 1;
                    else
                        modeMap[el]++;
                    if (modeMap[el] > maxCount) {
                        maxEl = el;
                        maxCount = modeMap[el];
                    }
                }            
                return maxEl;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I find it, just add : var userResponses = this.userResponses.filter(Boolean);